# Android sqlite DB strange behavior

Tags: android, sqlite

I am running a query in sqllite browser which gives the output fine.

But when i am running the query through Android's SqlLiteDatabase's rawQuery function it returns 3 rows for every original row

The query being -

```
   select s.shout_id, u.user_id, u.image_id , u.firstname, u.lastname, s.shout_msg , i.user_id 'r_user_id' , i.image_id 'r_img_id', i.firstname 'r_firstname', i.lastname 'r_lastname', s.rec_time from shouts s left join users u 
            on s.user_id = u.user_id left join users i on s.reciever_id = i.user_id
            where ((s.user_id =1 and s.reciever_id =2) or (s.user_id =2 and s.reciever_id =1) ) and s.shout_id < 5  order by s.shout_id desc limit 20;
```

The raw query code being in android -

```
public Cursor get_friend_shouts_less(String myid, String friend_id, long shout_id) {
    open();
    Log.d("ListView1", "get less Message myid friend_id shout_id: " + myid + " " + friend_id + " " + shout_id );
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select s.shout_id, u.user_id, u.image_id , u.firstname, u.lastname, s.shout_msg , i.user_id 'r_user_id' , i.image_id 'r_img_id', i.firstname 'r_firstname', i.lastname 'r_lastname', s.rec_time from shouts s left join users u " +
            "on s.user_id = u.user_id left join users i on s.reciever_id = i.user_id" +
            " where ((s.user_id =? and s.reciever_id =?) or (s.user_id =? and s.reciever_id =?) ) and s.shout_id < ? order by s.shout_id desc limit 60;", new String[]{myid, friend_id, friend_id, myid , String.valueOf(shout_id)});
    return c;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to group by id?

Comment: thanks @Rüdiger that solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad it worked, now my official Answer:

A SQL LEFT JOIN Operation is equal to an karthesian product AxB, which can lead to rows wih the same content. In "simple": using  GROUP BY merges those identical rows.

Comment: depends on the implementation engine, worked without the group by in "sqlite browser"